# Required do html nao está funcionando

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou criando um site e estou usando angular, e no unico input existente o required nao está funcionando, ou seja, mesmo clicando no botao submit esta enviando o dado vazio para o banco, o que pode ser?

```js
 $scope.adicionaTopico = function (topico) {
     console.log(topico.assunto);
        console.log(topico.descricao);
    $http({
        url: URL + '/topico/cadastrar',
        method: "POST",
        data: {
                'assunto': topico.assunto,
                'idUsuario':1,
                'situacao': 'ATIVO',
                'datahora': new Date(),
                'descricao': topico.descricao,
                'grau':'1'
              }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
          $location.path('/');
    },
    function(response) { // optional
        alert("Erro!!!" + response);
    });
};
```

```html
<label for="descricao" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Descrição:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" name="desc" class="form-control" id="desc" placeholder="Seja especifico" ng-model="topico.descricao" required="required">
    </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="adicionaTopico(topico)">Criar Tópico</button>
```

Comment: Atenção que o  required="required" so funciona com HTML5 o melhor que voce deveria fazer era a verificação do lado do servidor por exemplo em php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca dentro de um formulário.

```
<form>
<label for="descricao" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Descrição:</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <input type="text" name="desc" class="form-control" id="desc" placeholder="Seja especifico" ng-model="topico.descricao" required="required">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="adicionaTopico(topico)">Criar Tópico</button>
</form>
```